# Using Travis to deploy to GitHub and build Tag

Tags: github, continuous-integration, travis-ci

I am struggling for some time on how to use Travis-CI to build and deploy a tag to GitHub.
I find some information about that on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21628642/call-github-api-with-travis-to-build-tag), but it is not very clear and it is also not working for me.

I created a new Release version 0.0.0 on gitHub and I am using Scala with Play Framework and my `.travis.yml` file is as follows:

```
language: scala
scala:
- 2.10.4
jdk:
- openjdk7

services:
- postgresql

env:
- PLAY_VERSION=2.0.2 DATABASE_USER=postgres DATABASE_PWD='' DATABASE_URL=jdbc:postgresql:testdb  BUILD_KEY=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

before_script:
- psql -c 'create database testdb;' -U postgres
- wget http://download.playframework.org/releases/play-${PLAY_VERSION}.zip
- unzip -q play-${PLAY_VERSION}.zip
- sudo apt-get install jq
script:
- sbt test
after_success:
  - play-${PLAY_VERSION}/play dist
  - 'ASSETID=$(curl -s -H "Authorization: token ${BUILD_KEY}" "https://api.github.com/repos/Company/spinsurstaging/releases/456729/assets" | jq ".[0].id")'
  - 'curl -XDELETE -s -H "Authorization: token ${BUILD_KEY}" "https://api.github.com/repos/Company/spinsurstaging/releases/assets/$ASSETID"'
  - 'curl -XPOST -s -H "Authorization: token ${BUILD_KEY}" -H "Content-Type: application/zip" --data-binary @./spinsurstaging-0.0-SNAPSHOT.zip "https://uploads.github.com/repos/Company/spinsurstaging/releases/456729/assets?name= spinsurstaging.zip"'

notifications:
email: false

deploy:
  provider: heroku
  api_key: "${HEROKU_KEY}"
  app: spinsurstaging
```

Main question is: How to make it work? Is something wrong?
And also: I didn't understand how I will post the file `spinsurstaging-0.0-SNAPSHOT.zip` as a release to github. Where is this file coming from? Is there a standard for this?
Is there a better way to do that?

Thank you in advance for helping me out with this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just figured out how to solve it.
I made a mistake on the line of code:

`- 'curl -XPOST -s -H "Authorization: token ${BUILD_KEY}" -H "Content-Type: application/zip" --data-binary @./spinsurstaging-0.0-SNAPSHOT.zip "https://uploads.github.com/repos/Company/spinsurstaging/releases/456729/assets?name= spinsurstaging.zip"'`

The correct code is:

`- 'curl -XPOST -s -H "Authorization: token ${BUILD_KEY}" -H "Content-Type: application/zip" --data-binary @./spinsurstaging-0.0-SNAPSHOT.zip  "https://uploads.github.com/repos/Company/spinsurstaging/releases/456729/assets?name= spinsurstaging .zip"'`

Note that I change the snapshot filename. This snapshot is created when running the command `play-${PLAY_VERSION}/play dist`

Another important thing is that I have to change the `PLAY_VERSION` variable to `2.2.4` because the older version didn't had a repository for the same version I was using for sbt.

So I believe I could answer all my questions. Hope it helps someone else. Here are the complete solution:

```
language: scala
scala:
- 2.10.4
jdk:
- openjdk7

services:
- postgresql

env:
- PLAY_VERSION=2.2.4 DATABASE_USER=postgres DATABASE_PWD='' DATABASE_URL=jdbc:postgresql:testdb  BUILD_KEY=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

before_script:
- psql -c 'create database testdb;' -U postgres
- wget http://downloads.typesafe.com/play/${PLAY_VERSION}/play-${PLAY_VERSION}.zip
- unzip -q play-${PLAY_VERSION}.zip
- sudo apt-get install jq
script:
- sbt test
after_success:
  - play-${PLAY_VERSION}/play dist
  - cd target/universal/
  - 'ASSETID=$(curl -s -H "Authorization: token ${BUILD_KEY}" "https://api.github.com/repos/Company/spinsurstaging/releases/456729/assets" | jq ".[0].id")'
  - 'curl -XDELETE -s -H "Authorization: token ${BUILD_KEY}" "https://api.github.com/repos/Company/spinsurstaging/releases/assets/$ASSETID"'
  - 'curl -XPOST -s -H "Authorization: token ${BUILD_KEY}" -H "Content-Type: application/zip" --data-binary @./spinsurstaging-1.0-SNAPSHOT.zip "https://uploads.github.com/repos/Company/spinsurstaging/releases/456729/assets?name= spinsurstaging'

notifications:
email: false

deploy:
  provider: heroku
  api_key: "${HEROKU_KEY}"
  app: spinsurstaging
```