# push github release requirements

Tags: git, github, deployment, release, travis-ci

I have been trying to follow the various guides to pushing a release to GitHub, but I am missing some crucial information.

What is required for such a push to work?

This is my .travis.yml

```
language: java
git:
  submodules: false
deploy:
  provider: releases
  api_key:
    secure: JjpBYKmA8ByMiNEXLQcR...
  file: target/uSkyBlock.jar
  release-number: latest
  skip_cleanup: true
  on:
    tags: true
    repo: rlf/uSkyBlock
    branch: v2.0.0
    all_branches: true
cache:
  directories:
  - $HOME/.m2
```

I.e. if I want the CI to push SNAPSHOT releases, what should and what shouldn't I do?

I've tried adding and or removing the `on:tags` clause, and various other efforts, but regardless, I get the following when trying to deploy:

> /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/octokit-3.7.0/lib/octokit/response/raise_error.rb:16:in `on_complete': GET https://api.github.com/repos/rlf/uSkyBlock/releases/latest: 404 - Not Found // See: https://developer.github.com/v3 (Octokit::NotFound)
>     from /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/faraday-0.9.0/lib/faraday/response.rb:9:in`block in call'
>     from /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/faraday-0.9.0/lib/faraday/response.rb:57:in `on_complete'
>     from /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/faraday-0.9.0/lib/faraday/response.rb:8:in`call'
>     from /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/faraday-0.9.0/lib/faraday/rack_builder.rb:139:in `build_response'
>     from /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/faraday-0.9.0/lib/faraday/connection.rb:377:in`run_request'
>     from /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/faraday-0.9.0/lib/faraday/connection.rb:140:in `get'
>     from /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/sawyer-0.6.0/lib/sawyer/agent.rb:94:in`call'
>     from /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/octokit-3.7.0/lib/octokit/client.rb:339:in `request'
>     from /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/octokit-3.7.0/lib/octokit/client.rb:135:in`get'
>     from /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/octokit-3.7.0/lib/octokit/client/releases.rb:41:in `release'
>     from /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/dpl-1.7.8/lib/dpl/provider/releases.rb:105:in`block in push_app'
>     from /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/dpl-1.7.8/lib/dpl/provider/releases.rb:102:in `each'
>     from /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/dpl-1.7.8/lib/dpl/provider/releases.rb:102:in`push_app'
>     from /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/dpl-1.7.8/lib/dpl/provider.rb:131:in `block in deploy'
>     from /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/dpl-1.7.8/lib/dpl/cli.rb:41:in`fold'
>     from /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/dpl-1.7.8/lib/dpl/provider.rb:131:in `deploy'
>     from /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/dpl-1.7.8/lib/dpl/cli.rb:32:in`run'
>     from /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/dpl-1.7.8/lib/dpl/cli.rb:7:in `run'
>     from /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/dpl-1.7.8/bin/dpl:5:in`'
>     from /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/bin/dpl:23:in `load'
>     from /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/bin/dpl:23:in`'
>   failed to deploy

- (existing tag) https://travis-ci.org/rlf/uSkyBlock/builds/44196529
- (non-existing tag) https://travis-ci.org/rlf/uSkyBlock/builds/44182870

It seems the `releases` deploy module can't locate my snapshots on GitHub.

So, If I want travis to deploy a continuous test-release to GitHub - what do I have to do?
What am I missing?

Comment: I've done some more digging, and it seems, that the releases.rb fails when trying to GET the releases from GitHub.
I'm wondering whether it's the way I added the api-key that is causing the problems - but I'd rather not commit my username/pw in cleartext - since this is a public repo.

Comment: Relevant issues, using Curl directly, without the deploy thingy from travis.
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21628642/call-github-api-with-travis-to-build-tag
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25028765/using-travis-to-deploy-to-github-and-build-tag?lq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After absolutely no help on these forums, and no answer on IRC - here is my solution to the problem.

It's a hybrid between "the guide" from travis, and the bits and pieces picked up on various related questions.

```
travis setup releases
```

Will do it's best, but for me, something failed, and I couldn't get back on track.
So, the solution was:

a) Find and install `travis-cli` - I managed to do this on my Windows box, though it's way easier on Linux (though, that is kind of needed for the above step, it's still something that needs to be done).

b) Go to the GitHub Settings page under Applications and locate the "automatic releases for rlf/uSkyBlock".

c) Regenerate a new key - and copy it (it will be gone if you don't).

d) Launch the travis-cli, and encrypt the key:

```
travis encrypt GITHUB_TOKEN=mytokenhere --add
```

e) Use the environment variable in your `.travis.yml`

```
deploy:
  api-key: ${GITHUB_TOKEN}
```

and now it seems to work.

No need to mess with Curl, or the GitHub API - and no need to wait for travis-ci to answer your question.